# Microsoft Outlook 2016 Error 0x800ccc0e

Tags: account-recovery, outlook-365

I changed my password for my Outlook account on my phone. Now I can't update my inbox on my computer. When I try and send/receive all folders I am getting an error message (Error 0x800ccc0e). I tried changing my password for my Outlook account in Google Chrome but that didn't seem to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome. Try over your phone again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, there might be several reasons for getting this [Outlook IMAP Error 0x800CCC0E while sending/receiving mails](http://www.webrho.com/resolved-outlook-error-0x800ccc0e-imap-windows-10/) through IMAP account.

It can't be server problem I suppose for the problem happens to two different mail servers on two different Windows operating systems.

Are the two computer in the same networking environment? If so, please first make sure that the internet connection is fine and stable. We may try to logon to the web mail interface of your Gmail and Yahoo account in browser to verify this.

One of the reasons to getting this error code is wrong port numbers, please also make sure that the port numbers are set correctly for your incoming and outgoing mail server. See the following Microsoft KB article to verify whether you set the port numbers correctly:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2758902/how-to-set-up-an-internet-email-account-in-outlook-2013-or-2016

In addition, several community members who encountered the same error code could fix the issue via the following method, you may also have a try with it:

1. Navigate to File > Options > Advanced, scroll down to the Send/Receive section and click on the Send/Receive button on the right.
2. On the right hand side of the Send/Receive Groups window that opens click on the Edit button.
3. Un-check the "Get folder unread count for subscribed folders"
4. Under Received mail items, check the option "User the custom behavior defined below"
5. In the window below that displays your Gmail/Yahoo folders just select inbox and leave the others unchecked
6. Click OK and then exit out of options and perform a send/receive to test if it is now working